# Is it possible to create an org-mode *scratch* buffer?

Tags: org-mode, scratch-buffer

While working on a document in emacs I often find myself opening a new buffer, doing something in org-mode, copying the org-mode content, and pasting it into my document. I used to create a new org-mode document every time I needed to do this. Now I have a file `~/.scratch.org` where I keep my this work.

Would it be possible to create an `*org-scratch*` buffer that behaved analogously to the `*scratch*` buffer?

Comment: Is there anything inconvenient with doing `M-x` `org-mode` when you're in `*scratch*` buffer?

Comment: @XiangJi Didn't even think to do that. That's a great idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The initial major-mode for the `*Scratch*` buffer is controlled by the variable `initial-major-mode` -- the value needs to be a symbol (which in layman's terms means put a single quote in front of the major-mode name):  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode 'org-mode)
```

---

**EDIT**:  Based on a comment of the original poster, here is a sample function to create non-file-visiting buffers in sequential order with the major-mode of `org-mode`:

```lisp
(defun my-scratch-buffer ()
"Create a new scratch buffer -- \*hello-world\*"
(interactive)
  (let ((n 0)
        bufname buffer)
    (catch 'done
      (while t
        (setq bufname (concat "*hello-world"
          (if (= n 0) "" (int-to-string n))
            "*"))
        (setq n (1+ n))
        (when (not (get-buffer bufname))
          (setq buffer (get-buffer-create bufname))
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (org-mode))
          ;; When called non-interactively, the `t` targets the other window (if it exists).
          (throw 'done (display-buffer buffer t))) ))))
```

Comment: So would it be possible to have two `*Scratch*` buffers then?

Comment: I added a sample function that creates new non-file-visiting buffers in numerical order, and I included an `org-mode` designation.  The name can be changed from `hello-world` to anything the user desires that is recognized by the operating system -- e.g., Windows doesn't like astrisks.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: I am happy to have been able to help.  I decided to throw the result and display the buffer in one fell swoop -- the functionality is the same, but the function looks a little more compact this way.  :)

Comment: When we call `my-scratch-buffer` can it be open in full window instead of splitting normal window in to half size?

Comment: @alper -- If you wish to target the currently selected window, then you can change `(display-buffer buffer t)` to `(switch-to-buffer buffer)`

Answer (score 10):

There's an extension called [`scratch`](https://github.com/ieure/scratch-el), which allows creating mode-specific scratch buffers. It is available from MELPA, so you should be able to install it easily.

With this package installed, when you are in an `org-mode` buffer, you can run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`scratch` to get a scratch buffer in `org-mode`.

If you give a prefix argument, you get the opportunity to choose the mode (instead of selecting the currently active major mode).

Comment: I tried this but I think the scratch buffer gets deleted after you quit emacs. The original scratch buffer doesn't, it saves itself automatically too. Is this right or did I miss something?

Comment: Unless you do something special, the original `*scratch*` buffer doesn't persist across sessions, nor is it saved when you exit emacs.  Try running `emacs -q` to get the standard behaviour, unmodified by your init file.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I have just investigated this and I found out it is a feature of Aquamacs. I also found out that Aquamacs comes with the keybinding Command-N to create a new scratch in another frame (this one not persistent across sessions).

Comment: By the way, there is a package on MELPA called persistent-scratch which claim to create persistent scratch buffers.

Answer (score 6):

I think one simple way to achieve it is simply to run `M-x org-mode` when you're in `*snatch*` buffer, and thus enabling `org-mode` directly. This can be applied to enabling any major mode.

Comment: The simplest way by far.

Comment: This is certainly useful. I like having a scratch buffer exclusively devoted to org-mode since I often use the scratch buffer for other things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. C-x b (type a name for your new scratch buffer, e.g. "asdf")
2. M-x org-mode (change "asdf" buffer's major mode)

When closing this buffer you won't get a query for saving its contents. I.e. you get a proper scratch buffer. And the `*scratch*` buffer remains intact.