# Perp-mode - open new blank tab without prompts?

Tags: evil, spacemacs

I'm trying to replicate vims :tabnew functionality, which just creates a new empty tab (perspective). All the commands I've looked at prompts for confirmations and names etc. They clone the current tab and do not automatically switch.

Is there a command that will create a new (empty) tab, give it a default name (I'll name it later if I want) and switch to it?

Comment: Here is a custom function to create a new blank buffer in a particular major-mode that a user has pre-defined:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287  It automatically numbers successively created new buffers.  I have it set up to display without selecting, but it can easily be modified to `switch-to-buffer-other-widndow` instead of `display-buffer`.  New buffers can be any major-mode you want.  It must have a buffer-name, but it is not automatically saved as a file.  We call this a non-file-visiting-buffer.

Comment: If you need help with a minor-mode called `tabbar-mode`, please update your question to further clarify the issue.

Comment: No, I'm using persp-mode, as the title says.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [scratch](https://github.com/ieure/scratch-el)?

It will create a new empty buffer according the current buffer mode without prompts and switch to it immediately.

Comment: But it won't create a new tab at all will it?

Comment: @flukus No, maybe I misunderstood your needs at the first place, scratch won't create a new tab but a new buffer. As @lawlist said, you can use `tabbar-mode`, but tab is not very useful in Emacs (at least I never use it), modify the snippet in the answer of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287 and bind it to a key, you'll get what you want.