# Change scratch buffer to org mode by default

Tags: org-mode

When I test some codes in scratch buffer, usually first set it as org mode manually.

How could config it as 'org mode' rather than fundamental mode by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a link to another thread you may be interested in, entitled "**Is it possible to create an org-mode *scratch* buffer?**":

[Is it possible to create an org-mode *scratch* buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16492/is-it-possible-to-create-an-org-mode-scratch-buffer)

New buffers that are *not* the `*scratch*` buffer, *should* default to `fundamental-mode`; e.g., when calling `get-buffer-create`.  As to the `*scratch*` buffer, you can customize the `initial-major-mode` variable:

```
initial-major-mode is a variable defined in ‘startup.el’.
Its value is ‘lisp-interaction-mode’

Documentation:
Major mode command symbol to use for the initial ‘*scratch*’ buffer.

You can customize this variable.
```

Thus, use the following:

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode 'org-mode)
```

Comment: Also it may be useful to set `initial-scratch-message`

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you know: `M-x ielm` will open IELM: a proper read-eval-print loop (REPL) for Elisp. Take a look at its documentation string (`C-h f ielm RET`) to get an idea of how powerful and flexible it is.

I find IELM much more useful and usable than either `lisp-interaction-mode` -- the default mode for `*scratch*`, as noted by @lawlist -- or Org mode. Coding is about the only thing Org is not good for. :-)

[REPL article at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)