# How do I show initial-scratch-message when the *scratch* buffer is recreated?

Tags: scratch-buffer

By default, a `*scratch*` buffer is created when Emacs starts. The initial `*scratch*` buffer contains the following message by default:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.
```

This message appears to be set by the variable `initial-scratch-message`.

If I kill (`C-x k`) the initial scratch buffer and recreate it using `C-x b *scratch*`, the new scratch buffer will be blank. It will not contain the `initial-scratch-message`. This is not what I want. I want to see the message. How do I configure all scratch buffers to contain `initial-scratch-message` when they are recreated?

Comment: Here is a link to an idea you may wish to use to create scratch buffers.  You can use `(insert ...)` to insert text wherever you want, just run a test to see whether the buffer already exists so you don't insert the same text twice. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287  You can modify the example to make it be whatever `major-mode` you want, or even just `fundamental-mode` if so desired.  When the `*scratch*` buffer is created *automatically* by Emacs, you may wish to use a custom function attached to the variable `initial-major-mode` which does more than just set major-mode.

Comment: NOTE:  When the O.P. "*recreate[s] it using `C-x b *scratch*`*", the O.P. is merely creating a new generic/vanilla buffer with no particular major-mode.  It is just like creating a new buffer named `*foo*` or `*bar*` or `*baz*`.  The question, as written, seems to imply that the O.P. believes the newly created buffer named `*scratch*` may have had some special relationship to the *initial* `*scratch*` buffer beyond having the same buffer-name.

Comment: @lawlist When I recreate a scratch buffer using `C-x b *scratch*`, I get a Lisp interaction mode buffer. I am using GNU Emacs 25.2.2.

Comment: Thank you -- you are correct.  The internal function `set-buffer-major-mode` within `buffer.c` will run the function attached to the `initial-major-mode` variable if the buffer-name is `*scratch*`.  The Lisp function `window-normalize-buffer-to-switch-to` within `window.el` calls `set-buffer-major-mode`.  Therefore, creating a custom function and attaching it to the `initial-major-mode` variable seems like the most appropriate course of action given your desire to use the buffer-name `*scratch*`.  Thank you for providing me with the opportunity/incentive to trace the aforementioned items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal function `set-buffer-major-mode` within `buffer.c` will run the function attached to the `initial-major-mode` variable if the buffer-name is `*scratch*`.  The Lisp function `window-normalize-buffer-to-switch-to` within `window.el` calls `set-buffer-major-mode`.  Therefore, creating a custom function and attaching it to the `initial-major-mode` variable seems like the most appropriate course of action given the desire by the O.P. to use the buffer-name `*scratch*`.  Using `substitute-command-keys` in conjunction with the `initial-scratch-message` will transform `\\[find-file]` into `C-x C-f`.

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode (lambda ()
                           (insert (substitute-command-keys initial-scratch-message))
                           (lisp-interaction-mode)))
```

The default value of the variable `initial-scratch-message` in Emacs 27.1 is:

```
(purecopy "\
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with \\[find-file] and enter text in its buffer.

")
```