# Unique name for buffer

Tags: buffers

Is it possible for emacs to give me a unique name for a buffer?  I am making some new buffers and want to automatically name it without asking the user for a name.

Have started with the following

```
(defun workspace ()
  "todo"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window name)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (lisp-interaction-mode)) )

(defun new-buffer ()
  "Open a new empty buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ( ($buf (generate-new-buffer "untitled")) )
    ;; switch to buffer
    (switch-to-buffer $buf)
    (funcall (and lisp-interaction-mode))))
```

I want the user to either accept the unique name or write one himself.

Comment: I think if you had searched for other questions about unique buffer names then you would have found the answer already.

Comment: There are some descriptions but not many implementation examples

Comment: Here is a link to an example that uses a hard-coded specific name and then concatenates an integer to create a unique buffer name:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287

Comment: Each of them has documentation that you can access with `C-h f`. Read them, decide which function does what you want, and proceed.

Comment: I shall proceed with `generate-new-buffer` because it always creates a new buffer and gives it a unique name.

Comment: Then you have found your solution as was foretold by the ancient prophecies.

Comment: Indeed.  My life is spared.